# paperclip imagemagick convert to grayscale and crop to fit 144x144#

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, imagemagick, paperclip

**Client.rb**

```
  has_attached_file :avatar,
  :path => ":rails_root/public/system/:attachment/:id/:style/:filename",
  :url => "/system/:attachment/:id/:style/:filename",
  :styles => {:thumb => "144x144#", :grayscale => { :processors => [:grayscale] }}
```

The thumb version version works great, the image is cropped to the required size, the grayscale only converts that image to grayscale, but the image is not being cropped, here are the grayscale generator that I found on StackOverflow:

**lib/grayscale.rb**

```
module Paperclip
  # Handles grayscale conversion of images that are uploaded.
  class Grayscale < Processor

    def initialize file, options = {}, attachment = nil
      super
      @format = File.extname(@file.path)
      @basename = File.basename(@file.path, @format)
    end

     def make
       src = @file
       dst = Tempfile.new([@basename, @format])
       dst.binmode

       begin
         parameters = []
         parameters << ":source"
         parameters << "-colorspace Gray"
         parameters << ":dest"

         parameters = parameters.flatten.compact.join(" ").strip.squeeze(" ")

         success = Paperclip.run("convert", parameters, :source => "#{File.expand_path(src.path)}[0]", :dest => File.expand_path(dst.path))
       rescue PaperclipCommandLineError => e
         raise PaperclipError, "There was an error during the grayscale conversion for #{@basename}" if @whiny
       end

       dst
     end
  end
end
```

To convert an image to grayscale some params are being sent to imagemagick in an array, the **question** is - what params do I have to send to imagemagick so it will do exactly what `"144x144#"` do in paperclip.

I tried to follow the logs to see what this `"144x144#"` looks like in logs, it was looking like this: `-crop '144x144+30+0'`, I tried to use it in my generator and send it as params like:

```
 parameters = []
 parameters << ":source"
 parameters << "-crop '144x144+30+0'"
 parameters << "-colorspace Gray"
 parameters << ":dest"
```

and looked like it worked if I used the same image that I uploaded before, if I upload another one the image is cropped completely wrong. So I came to a conclusion that param: `-crop '144x144+30+0'` that were generated by paperclip was for that specific image size, and for another with different size normally different params will be sent to fit to 144px.

How do I crop the image in generator to fit to equivalent of `144x144#` from paperclip or what are the params I need to send to imagemagick to achieve this. Thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I decided to go the other way, so I'll just use the cropped file that has the desired size and use imagemagick to convert that one to grayscale and save it into the right folder after the model is saved. The grayscale processor can be removed as I used a system command to work with imagemagick.

p.s. There might be some downsides of this answer, but for now I couldn't find any.

**Client.rb**

```
  has_attached_file :avatar,
  :path => ":rails_root/public/system/:attachment/:id/:style/:filename",
  :url => "/system/:attachment/:id/:style/:filename",
  :styles => {:thumb => "144x144#", :grayscale => "144x144#"}

  after_save :convert_grayscale

  def convert_grayscale
    system "convert public/system/avatars/#{self.id}/thumb/#{self.avatar.original_filename} -fx '(r+g+b)/3' public/system/avatars/#{self.id}/grayscale/#{self.avatar.original_filename}"
  end
```

---

**result**

[image]

Answer (score 3):

To keep things simple, you can append to `convert` directly with, `convert_options:`

e.g.

```
  has_attached_file :file, styles: {
    ir: '640x640>', 
    thumb: '150x150>'
  }
```

BECOMES:

```
  has_attached_file :file, styles: {
    ir: {geometry: '640x640>', convert_options: '-colorspace Gray'}, 
    thumb: '150x150>'
  }
```

Comment: This is by far the cleanest option. Thanks for this, @TomDunning!

Answer (score 2):

Through trial and error, I found a simpler way to do this. Using the grayscale processor code you found, put it in **lib/paperclip/grayscale.rb**.

Then, set your styles like so:

```
:styles => {
  :thumb => "144x144#",
  :grayscale => { :geometry => "144x144#", :processors => [:grayscale, :thumbnail] }
}
```

This way, the grayscale style will be processed by both the grayscale processor and the thumbnail processor using the "geometry" provided. As a bonus, you'll be able to use Paperclip's built in rake tasks to reprocess existing attachments.